# Exact synatx of Datetime field in POST

Tags: jquery, mongodb, post, tastypie

I am trying to send date_time from jQuery post to our server we are using mongoDB as backend and using django_tastypie_mongoengine for posting so far i have tried putting date="2010-11-10T03:07:43" and also date="2013-05-21T02:17:55.544000" in my jQuery but it is failing everytime.

models.py:

```
class ProblemDetail(Document):
    date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

API.py

```
class ProblemDetailResource(resources.MongoEngineResource)

class Meta:

    queryset = ProblemDetail.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'problem'
    allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete','patch')
    authorization = authorization.Authorization()
```

html page

```
var date = "2000-11-10T03:07:43"

data = JSON.stringify({"date":date})

$.ajax({

url: 'http://xyz.in/api/v1/problem/?format=json',

type: 'POST',            

contentType: 'application/json',

data: data,

dataType: 'json',

processData: false,

success: function(data){

alert("done!")

}
```

I want to know the exact syntax of sending date

Comment: Why don't you store the datetime string in milliseconds? This is the easiest way to avoid conflicts between a programming language and a database system.

Comment: thanks @reporter for help but for that i have to use StringField in mongoDB is there a way to POST that in datetime Field only

Comment: Uhm are you sure that the String '2000-11-10T03:07:43' is a correct timestring in Javascript? In my eyes not, though I could be properbly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer:

```
var date = new Date()
date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate() + 'T' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' +d.getSeconds()

settings.py
USE_TZ = True
```

the time zone that comes in new Date() is the reason for error in many development servers.
I was using Python with Django and app was deployed in apache